# Connecting UF wiring for under deck lighting to an existing NM exterior light switch

Tags: electrical, lighting, deck

I plan on installing LED lights under my dry-below deck using 14-2 UF Romex. Can I connect the UF wire to an existing exterior light (NM Romex) that is switched from inside the house? If not, do I have to run the UF back to the panel and install a separate switch to control the new LED lights? Switching the new lights from the existing switch would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact, UF wire can be treated just like NM wire when ran indoors.

#### 340.10 Uses Permitted

*4. Installed as nonmetallic-sheathed cable. Where so installed, the installation and conductor requirements shall comply with Parts II and III of Article 334 and shall be of the multiconductor type.*
*Including the ampacity adjustment in 334.80.*